# python double for statements & networks: [nodes for v in links for nodes in v]

Tags: python, social-networking, list-comprehension

I'm trying to generate a network with preferential attachment.

So I'll start out with two nodes connected by an edge:

```
links = [[1],[0]]
```

I have sample code:

```
weighted = [nodes for v in links for nodes in v]
```

Could someone translate what [something] for v in [list] for [something] in v might mean? I'm only used to the syntax for i in list: {do stuff}

Comment: [List comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 2):

```
weighted_nodes = []
for v in links:
    for nodes in v:
        weighted_nodes.append(nodes)
```

is essentially what it is doing

Answer (score 0):

That's a nested list comprehension.  That particular form is used to flatten a nested list.

```
a = [['a','b'],['c','d','e']]

[elem for sublist in a for elem in sublist]
Out[43]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia:

> A list comprehension is a syntactic construct available in some
>   programming languages for creating a list based on existing lists. It
>   follows the form of the mathematical set-builder notation (set
>   comprehension) as distinct from the use of map and filter functions.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension